# Why probability is unchanged?

Tags: probability

This is a question which I solved but the answer seems intriguing so I am asking for insight.

There are two boxes $B_1$ and $B_2$. $B_1$ has $n$ red colored balls and $m$ green colored balls and $B_2$ has $x$ red colored balls and $y$ green colored balls. $1$ ball is transferred randomly from the box $B_1$ to box $B_2$. What is the probability of drawing a red colored ball from box $B_1$ now?

Prior to transfer, the probability of drawing a red ball from box $B_1$ is $\frac{n}{n+m}$. Also, after the transfer, the probability is same.

I got the probability correct but I am not able to understand why the results are same. Is their a logical explanation so that the question need not be solved mathematically to get the answer but rather derived from a logical thinking?

Comment: Think of it this way:  suppose the balls were numbered $R_1, \cdots, R_n, G_1,\cdots, G_m$.  Arrange the balls in a line according to the draws.  Each ball then has an equal probability of being at any point in the line.  Thus the probability of getting, say, $R_1$ on the second draw is $\frac 1{n+m}$ and so on.  Thus the probability of getting red on the second try is $\frac n{n+m}$.  Clearly this reasoning extends to the third draw, the fourth, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the probability that the second draw is red, but let's not stop there.  Suppose we draw out all the $n+m$ balls.

Let's imagine that the balls are numbered, $R_1,\cdots, R_n,G_1,\cdots G_m$.  Drawing all of them is the same as putting them in a line, so we are asking for a random permutation of those $n+m$ balls.  Random here means that each ball has an equal probability of being in any given position in line. Thus, the probability that you draw, say, $R_1$ in the $k^{th}$ draw is $\frac 1{n+m}$.  Continuing in this way, the probability that you draw a red ball in the $k^{th}$ draw is $\frac n{n+m}$.  Thus the probability that, say, the second draw is red, is $\frac n{n+m}$ as desired.

On a more informal basis, suppose that your way of making the first draw was to put your hands in the box, hold on to one ball but then extract a different one.  Surely you don't imagine that this process changes the probability that the extracted ball is red!  But that's exactly what you are doing by looking at the second draw.

Answer (score 0):

You need $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$.

First find the conditional probability given either you removed a green or a red.

Took red: $E[X = red|Y = red] = \frac{n-1}{n+m-1}$.

Took green: $E[X = red|Y = green] = \frac{n}{n+m-1}$.

Probability that you took red: $P(Y = red) = \frac{n}{n+m}$.

Probability that you took green: $P(Y = green) = \frac{m}{n+m}$.

$E[E[X = red|Y]] = P(Y = red).E[X = red|Y = red] + P(Y = green).E[X = red|Y = green]$

$E[E[X= red|Y]] = \frac{n}{n+m}.\frac{n-1}{n+m-1} + \frac{m}{n+m}.\frac{n}{n+m-1}$

$E[E[X= red|Y]] = \frac{n^2 + mn - n}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}$

$E[E[X= red|Y]] = \frac{n(n+m-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}$

$E[E[X= red|Y]] = \frac{n}{n+m}$.

Comment: I guess what I'm doing here is finding the expected number of red's pulled after one test. This is equivalent to the probability but feel free to write it as $E[P[X = red|Y]]$.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this qualifies as the OP's requested "logical explanation so that the question need not be solved mathematically"